# Linux asynchronous I/O queue

Tags: file, asynchronous, linux-kernel, device

In the context of block devices like a file; are Linux kernel AIO functions like `io_submit()` only asynchronous *within* the supplied queue of I/O operations, or are they (also) asynchronous across several prosesses and/or threads that also have queues of I/O operations on the same file.

> Doc says: The **io_submit()** system call queues nr I/O request blocks for
>   processing in the AIO context ctx_id.  The iocbpp argument should be
>   an array of nr AIO control blocks, which will be submitted to context
>   ctx_id.

**Update:**

Example: 
If I spawn two threads, both have 100 queued I/O operations on the same file and both call `io_submit()` at approx. the same time; will *all* 200 I/O operations be asynchronous or will thread #1's 100 I/O operations only be asynchronous in regards to each other but block thread #2 until all thread #1's I/O operations are done?

Comment: I don't understand: for me asynchronous means "not synchronous with regards to a given instruction flow". If an instruction is synchronous, it is within that very instruction flow which it belongs to, and asynchronous to any other.

Comment: @didierc Example: If I spawn two threads, both have 100 queued I/O operations on the same file and both call `io_submit()` at approx. the same time; will _all_ 200 I/O operations be asynchronous or will thread #1's 100 I/O operations only be asynchronous in regards to each other but block thread #2 until all thread #1's I/O operations are done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a set of io requests is submitted with `io_submit`, the system call returns immediately. From the point of view of the thread emitting the requests, the execution of the commands embedded in the requests is asynchronous. The thread will have to query the OS to know the result, and is free to do what it wants in the mean time.

Now, if two threads happens to emit each a set of requests, they will both fall in the same situation. They will both have to ask the OS about the advancement of their respective IO commands. None of the threads will be blocked.

From the AIO framework point of view, it is entirely possible to make the OS actually execute the requests *before* returning from the `io_submit` call for either or all the threads invoking it, but the API remains the same: userland threads will still manipulate the API as an async one, obtaining a token for a future result from the API when it posts its requests, and using that token to get the real result.

In the specific case of linux AIO, the token is the context created beforehand, and the result check syscall is `io_getevents`, which reports an "event" (ie. a result) for each completed request.

Regarding your example, is it possible that during the second syscall, all the requests of the first thread get completed?  I don't see a reason for this never happening at all, but if both threads post 100 requests very close to each other, then it seems very unlikely. A more likely scenario is that several requests of the first thread to call `io_submit` got completed when the second thread makes its own call to `io_submit`, but at any rate that call *will not block*.

Comment: not sure if I am really answering your question. let me know if there's something I missed here.

Answer (score 1):

The only PART of asynchronous behaviour that your application should care about is within your application. Yes, other processes are likely going to ALSO write data to the disk at some point during the runtime of your application. There is very little you can do to stop that in a multitasking, multiuser and potentially multiprocessor system.

The general idea here is that your application doesn't block, which is the way that `read` or `write` [and their more advanced cousins, `fread`, `fwrite`, etc).

If you want to stop other processes from touching "your" files, then you need to use file-locking or something similar.